# Why does scikit-image return the frame count of a video as a float?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I was wondering why scikit-image returns the frame count of a video as a float.  Is there ever an occasion when a video has a fractional number of frames?

This code snippet...

```
import skimage.io as io
v = io.Video('videos/intersection_cine.avi')
v.frame_count()
```

...returns 17313.0

Comment: If its interlaced and stops one field short you could call that half a frame...

Comment: Interestingly, according to the docs the output is *supposed* to be an int. http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html

Comment: Can you verify that the result is always an integer value?  If so, I'll glady make the change to cast to an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skimage.io.Video` works by using OpenCV, and for `frame_count` it uses OpenCV's function `GetCaptureProperty` which always returns a double no matter what property is passed.

This function, in turn, calls another function based on how/where the video capture was created. As an example, it could be based on GStreamer, which will always return an integer for `frame_count`. When using QuickTime instead, `frame_count` is defined as `movieDuration*movieFPS/1000` and therefore is a floating-point value.